# Hibernate Session is not open Using Javafx

Tags: hibernate, javafx

I am developing simple Application in Javafx with Hibernate using Netbeans 7.3.1

In the small project I have connected hibernate using Wizards Setup. I want to show company table data in TableView using hibernate. But when I run this app it is showing the error message below:

```
    INFO: building session factory
    Initial SessionFactory creation failed.net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException:     
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1440)
at 
    com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent
    (CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent
    (EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent
    (EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent
    (CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
```

---

I have the following files:

**1. hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration 
 DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
       org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
       jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.username">app</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.password">app</property>
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
     <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">
     org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
     <mapping resource="sample/entity/Company.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**2. hibernate.reveng.xml**

**3. HibernateUtil.java**

```
 package sample.util;
 import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
 import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
 public class HibernateUtil {
     private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
        // config file.
        sessionFactory = 
          new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log the exception. 
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}

**4. Company.java**
 package sample.entity;
 // Generated Aug 6, 2013 12:55:08 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA


import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Company generated by hbm2java
*/
public class Company  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer id;
 private String companyName;
 private String companyLogo;
 private String ownerName;
 private String address1;
 private String address2;
 private String city;
 private String state;
 private String pincode;
 private String countryCode;
 private String country;
 private String areaCode;
 private String offPhoneNo;
 private String offFaxNo;
 private String emailId;
 private String tanNo;
 private String panNo;
 private String website;
 private Date updt;
 private Date uptm;

public Company() {
}

public Company(String companyName, String companyLogo, String ownerName,
String address1, String address2, String city, String state, String pincode, 
String countryCode, String country, String areaCode, String offPhoneNo, 
String offFaxNo, String emailId, String tanNo, String panNo, String website, 
Date updt, Date uptm) {
   this.companyName = companyName;
   this.companyLogo = companyLogo;
   this.ownerName = ownerName;
   this.address1 = address1;
   this.address2 = address2;
   this.city = city;
   this.state = state;
   this.pincode = pincode;
   this.countryCode = countryCode;
   this.country = country;
   this.areaCode = areaCode;
   this.offPhoneNo = offPhoneNo;
   this.offFaxNo = offFaxNo;
   this.emailId = emailId;
   this.tanNo = tanNo;
   this.panNo = panNo;
   this.website = website;
   this.updt = updt;
   this.uptm = uptm;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getCompanyName() {
    return this.companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}
public String getCompanyLogo() {
    return this.companyLogo;
}

public void setCompanyLogo(String companyLogo) {
    this.companyLogo = companyLogo;
}
public String getOwnerName() {
    return this.ownerName;
}

public void setOwnerName(String ownerName) {
    this.ownerName = ownerName;
}
public String getAddress1() {
    return this.address1;
}

public void setAddress1(String address1) {
    this.address1 = address1;
}
public String getAddress2() {
    return this.address2;
}

public void setAddress2(String address2) {
    this.address2 = address2;
}
public String getCity() {
    return this.city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getState() {
    return this.state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public String getPincode() {
    return this.pincode;
}

public void setPincode(String pincode) {
    this.pincode = pincode;
}
public String getCountryCode() {
    return this.countryCode;
}

public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
    this.countryCode = countryCode;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return this.country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public String getAreaCode() {
    return this.areaCode;
}

public void setAreaCode(String areaCode) {
    this.areaCode = areaCode;
}
public String getOffPhoneNo() {
    return this.offPhoneNo;
}

public void setOffPhoneNo(String offPhoneNo) {
    this.offPhoneNo = offPhoneNo;
}
public String getOffFaxNo() {
    return this.offFaxNo;
}

public void setOffFaxNo(String offFaxNo) {
    this.offFaxNo = offFaxNo;
}
public String getEmailId() {
    return this.emailId;
}

public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
}
public String getTanNo() {
    return this.tanNo;
}

public void setTanNo(String tanNo) {
    this.tanNo = tanNo;
}
public String getPanNo() {
    return this.panNo;
}

public void setPanNo(String panNo) {
    this.panNo = panNo;
}
public String getWebsite() {
    return this.website;
}

public void setWebsite(String website) {
    this.website = website;
}
public Date getUpdt() {
    return this.updt;
}

public void setUpdt(Date updt) {
    this.updt = updt;
}
public Date getUptm() {
    return this.uptm;
}

public void setUptm(Date uptm) {
    this.uptm = uptm;
}
}
```

**5. Company.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Aug 6, 2013 12:55:08 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="sample.entity.Company" table="company" catalog="sample">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="Id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="companyName" type="string">
        <column name="CompanyName" length="100" />
    </property>
    <property name="companyLogo" type="string">
        <column name="CompanyLogo" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="ownerName" type="string">
        <column name="OwnerName" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="address1" type="string">
        <column name="Address1" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="address2" type="string">
        <column name="Address2" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="city" type="string">
        <column name="City" length="30" />
    </property>
    <property name="state" type="string">
        <column name="State" length="30" />
    </property>
    <property name="pincode" type="string">
        <column name="Pincode" length="10" />
    </property>
    <property name="countryCode" type="string">
        <column name="CountryCode" length="10" />
    </property>
    <property name="country" type="string">
        <column name="Country" length="30" />
    </property>
    <property name="areaCode" type="string">
        <column name="AreaCode" length="30" />
    </property>
    <property name="offPhoneNo" type="string">
        <column name="OffPhoneNo" length="15" />
    </property>
    <property name="offFaxNo" type="string">
        <column name="OffFaxNo" length="15" />
    </property>
    <property name="emailId" type="string">
        <column name="EmailId" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="tanNo" type="string">
        <column name="TanNo" length="35" />
    </property>
    <property name="panNo" type="string">
        <column name="PanNo" length="35" />
    </property>
    <property name="website" type="string">
        <column name="Website" length="30" />
    </property>
    <property name="updt" type="date">
        <column name="Updt" length="10" />
    </property>
    <property name="uptm" type="time">
        <column name="Uptm" length="8" />
    </property>
    </class>
   </hibernate-mapping>
```

Using the code below, I want to fetch data:

```
@FXML   
void initialize() {
    assert btnQuery != null : "fx:id=\"btnQuery\" was not injected: check your 
      FXML  file 'testing.fxml'.";
    assert tableview != null : "fx:id=\"tableview\" was not injected: check your 
      FXML file 'testing.fxml'.";
    assert txtName != null : "fx:id=\"txtName\" was not injected: check your 
      FXML file 'testing.fxml'.";
}
private String QUERY_ALL = "from Company";

@FXML
void btnQueryClick(ActionEvent event) {
    executeHQLQuery(QUERY_ALL);
}

private void executeHQLQuery(String hql) {

    try {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery(hql);   
        System.out.println(hql);
        List resultList = q.list();            
        displayResult(resultList);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        he.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the Exception generated:

```
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

Log output:

```
INFO: building session factory Initial SessionFactory creation failed.net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException:
   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null

   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle
      (FXMLLoader.java:1440)"
```

I have tried the same in a Simple Swing Application there the Hibernate connectivity is working fine, but using javafx it is showing troubles listed above.

Comment: You are trying to make a singleton to access your Hibernate session with HibernateUtil. I think you should take a look at Spring integration with JavaFX to make your singleton. Then you can define with Spring the way you interact with Hibernate. It needs a custom controller factory: when loading a FXML, javaFX has to know where the beans are defined (in this case: in a spring context). As you did not make a custom controller factory, I guess that Hibernate is badly instanciated (cglib proxies seem missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate in JavaFx is compatible with NetBeans 7.4 version.
NetBeans version 7.3 or below are not suitable for JavaFx.

Instead of making use of reverse engineering wizard. you can easily work with POJO's and mapping files.

Comment: what is process to create POJO

Comment: simply making a class file like ExampleDo and create all variables which you want to get value.... but primary key is necessary for all process

Comment: is it possible to automatically create Getter and Setter method in pojo.

Comment: using net beans you make it...just click on right click and then clik on getter setter method...and you can easily create POJO file.....hope this work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this without using the HibernateUtil class

you can get the session by following code. this is my controller part. and it worker fine for me

```
Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
List<Sample> results = null;

        try {

            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Sample.class);
            //cr.add(Restrictions.eq("qualification", "yes"));
            results = cr.list();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
        }
```